# How to check IIS 7 or 7+ is installed or not using innosetup?

Tags: iis-7.5, inno-setup

I want to check whether IIS 7 or 7+ is installed or not before my main installation starts in innosetup.
If IIS7 or 7+ is not available,an alert should be shown.
What condition i need to check?
can i get any function to achieve this task?

Comment: exactly version 7.5 or any IIS version ?

Comment: I'm thinking detecting IIS 7.5-only DLL / files exist or not using `FileExists()` function. But still finding out which file is IIS 7.5 only. Do you include IIS 7.5 Express version in your checking ?

Comment: sorry one small  change, i want to check IIS 7 or 7+ installed in end user pc,before my insallation starts, can i know how  to check that condition? is it possible to check the  condtion with the help of registy editor value like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Microsoft->InetStp->SetupString->IIS7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [`this example for NSIS`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Check_IIS_Version_Before_Installing), you might try the following code. The `IsIIS7AboveInstalled` function should return True if IIS at least in version 7 is installed, False otherwise:

```
[Code]
const
  IISRegKey = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp';

function GetIISVersion(var MajorVersion, MinorVersion: DWORD): Boolean;
begin
  Result := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, IISRegKey, 'MajorVersion', MajorVersion) and
    RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, IISRegKey, 'MinorVersion', MinorVersion);
end;

function IsIIS75AboveInstalled: Boolean;
var
  MajorVersion: DWORD;
  MinorVersion: DWORD;
begin
  Result := GetIISVersion(MajorVersion, MinorVersion) and (MajorVersion >= 7);
end;
```